# Find the eigenvalues of an identity matrix minus a rank 1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This problem comes from Linear Algebra and its Applications by David C Lay and Steven R Lay.

> Let $c$ be a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider the matrix $A = I - 2cc^T$

> a ) What are the eigenvalues of $A$?

> b) Find an easily computable eigenvector of $A$

My attempt:

Firstly we can see that $cc^T$ is a symmetric $rank\ 1$ matrix.

Let $v_i$ be a eigenvector of $A$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$

$$Av_i = \lambda_iv_i = (I - 2cc^T)v_i \\ = Iv_i - 2cc^Tv_i \\ = v_i  - 2cc^Tv_i$$

I'm stumped on where to go next. Is there something I'm missing?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345165/eigenvalues-of-householder-matrix

Answer (score 1):

First observe that
$$
Ac=(I-cc^T)c=c-cc^Tc=(1-c^Tc)c
$$
Hence, $c$ is an eigenvector, with eigenvalue $\lambda=1-c^Tc$.

Next, if $u$ and $v$ linearly independent and perpendicular to $c$, i.e., $c^Tu=c^Tv=0$, then
$$
Au=(I-cc^T)u=u, \quad Au=(I-cc^T)v=v.
$$
Hence the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\,1,\,1,\,1-c^Tc$.

Comment: Isn't $c^tc = 1$? since $c$ is a unit vector?  Therefore the 3rd eigenvalue is $0$